# preventDefault() not working on some code in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have some JS on my site that should prevent the following code from reloading the page (as I use AJAX to refresh part of it), but in IE it is always reloading the page. Every other browser is fine.

The JS, as givein in another thread -

```
$('#attachment-body').delegate("a", "click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The links that are still reloading the page (which is within the `#attachment-body` container) -

```
<div id="image-navigation">
    <div id="nav-previous" class="nav-previous attachment-nav-previous float-left">
        <p><a id="previous-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink($attachments[$previous_position]->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title($attachments[$previous_position]->post_title)); ?>" onclick="set_centre_image(<?php echo $attachments[$previous_position]->ID; ?>, <?php echo $previous_position; ?>)">&laquo; Previous Image</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-next" class="nav-next attachment-nav-next float-right">
        <p><a id="next-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink($attachments[$next_position]->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title($attachments[$next_position]->post_title)); ?>" onclick="set_centre_image(<?php echo $attachments[$next_position]->ID; ?>, <?php echo $next_position; ?>)">Next Image &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When rendered it this is the block of code generated by the above -

```
<div id="image-navigation">
    <div id="nav-previous" class="nav-previous attachment-nav-previous float-left">
        <p><a id="previous-link" href="http://mydomain.com/firm-news/summer-drinks-at-the-castle/summer-drinks-2011-6/" title="" onclick="set_centre_image(5144, 5)">&laquo; Previous Image</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-next" class="nav-next attachment-nav-next float-right">
        <p><a id="next-link" href="http://mydomain.com/firm-news/summer-drinks-at-the-castle/summer-drinks-2011-8/" title="" onclick="set_centre_image(5146, 7)">Next Image &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

`preventDefault()` works in IE as I use it in other areas of the site, so I can only think that something in my code is not right.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried live() instead of delegate(), or just plain click() if you're not dynamically generating the anchor tags?

Comment: Tried all 3. Doing some testing, I've it's not that `preventDefault()` isnt working - IE is not recognising `$('#attachment-body').delegate ...`, where as all the other browsers are. Thanks.

Comment: Might be that IE can't have an onClick attribute *and* a seperate binding. Try adding `return false;` to the onClick. Though I'd recommend not using onClick at all, and just bind elsewhere.

Comment: Good thought with the binding, but it cannot be that as I also use - `$('#post-related-image-thumbs a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});`
This works fine, on the thumbnails under the main image in the gallery. It's not `delegate()`, as that works in other places in IE. One thing I am noticing is that in IE, if I add `alert('Test');` to the code, it's not picking it up and showing the alert box, but yet somehow clicking on the main image works correctly, but the next/previous links just plain reload the page. Is there a way in IE of tracking exactly what JS is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved this now...

When a next/previous link in my gallery was clicked, it fired a JS function (using `onClick()`) that first cleared the div that I ran the `preventDefault()` agianst. Instead of that, I hid it and it now works.

I'm no expert, but it looks like IE tests for the `.delegate()`, `.live()` and `click()` methods after it fires the function specified inline (meaning that `#attachment-body` didn't exist at the point it was checking for it), where as other browsers do it the other way around.

Comment: delegate, live() and click() are from jQuery, hooking into the browser's events with addEventListener etc. in slightly different ways. Glad you got it working. Also, you might wish to move away from using onClick for assigning actions. It would mean better separation of content/logic, easier to read code, and the ability to assign multiple actions to the click event.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, but unfortunatly I pass data that is gathered on page load by PHP to the JS function (ID's and parents mainly), and as yet I don't know of a way to get that information dynamically without major changes to my code. One for the future I think.